# How to ssh into remote machine and create new user in bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh

I am writing a bash script and would like to ssh into a remote machine and execute the adduser command.  This is not working, all that I get is the --help text for adduser when I run the code below.

```
ssh backup@pizza.cs.fredonia.edu 'useradd $username; mkdir /home/$username;' || echo "Unable to create user on pizza.cs.fredonia.edu";;
```

Ubuntu 14.01

Comment: Are you using a literal `$username`? If so, where are you getting that from? Are you expecting the shell to expand it? When I run `useradd $username` in a local shell I get the help text.

Comment: Is the user `backup@pizza.cs.fedonia.edu` able to run `useradd`? You typically have to be root or `sudo useradd` assuming that the user backup has `sudo` rights.

Comment: That is what I now need to add, he does not have the rights to adduser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the double quote?  Inside single quotes, BASH will not expand the variable $username.

For example, if $username=bob, then this command will expand the variable:

```
ssh user@hostname "useradd $username; mkdir /home/$username;"
```

the quoted portion will expand to:

```
useradd bob; mkdir /home/bob;
```

But if you use single quotes, like this:

```
ssh user@hostname 'useradd $username; mkdir /home/$username;'
```

Then the quoted portion remains unchanged.  It will be interpreted as:

```
useradd $username; mkdir /home/$username;
```

BTW, the ; at the end, after $username, isn't necessary.